# Java error: Cannot convert void to double

Tags: java, sql

I have been trying to assign a value from an SQL database to a double within a void method but it keeps pooping up the error "Cannot convert from void to double". I have looked at many of such problems on this  site and none of them quite seem to cater to my current challenge.

Find attached the troublesome snippet of code.

```
public void credit(int userAccountNumber, double amount){
    ResultSet rs;
    try{

        double tempTotal;
        tempTotal = getTotalBalance.setString(1, Integer.toString(userAccountNumber));
        tempAvailable = getAvailableBalance.setString(1, Integer.toString(userAccountNumber));
        getAccount(userAccountNumber).credit(amount);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `getTotalBalance`? where's the code for the same? Is `setString` returning any value?

Comment: in which line ?show us the method

Comment: getTotalBalance is a PreparedStatement that contains only one variable. It is supposed to retrieve a double (TotalBalance) from a mySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these 2 lines is returning void and you are trying to assign that to a double.

```
  tempTotal = getTotalBalance.setString(1, Integer.toString(userAccountNumber));

    tempAvailable = getAvailableBalance.setString(1, Integer.toString(userAccountNumber));
```

Comment: Thank you! My eyes were kinda closed there. I now see my mistake.

Comment: We can stare at a problem for hours, then someone sees it in seconds. It happens to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As a setter, `setString` has the following signature :

```
public void setString(int i, String s)
```

What you need if you want a value returned is a proper getter :

```
public double getXXX(...){}
```